# Allow duplicate usernames with accounts-ui

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

There is a way to allow duplicates usernames (between different users) at sign Up using accounts-ui?  I'm using in configuration:

```
Accounts.ui.config({passwordSignupFields: ' USERNAME_AND_EMAIL' });
```

Usernames are allowed to be duplicates in my app (as facebook allow create different users with the same name) but only the email should be the unique between users for sign In later with email/password.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to [roll your own authentication](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/roll-your-own-authentication/).  Meteor Chef is a great place to start with this.

You won't be able to use `accounts-ui` to do this without hacking/changing it to suit your specific needs.

Best of luck to you buddy!

Comment: Thanks, I did that.   I have used this package: https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry   In the package settings I added an extrafield  "name" with html label "Username".   Later I should install this package locally to change some things like showing the username field before email and not after password as it do by default.   Also I have some troubles adding the new field in mongoDB which I finally resolve.  If people reading here have the same issue, please check my issue and solution in the github site of this package.

Comment: Good work Ruben, Thank you for responding here with the answer.  We can also edit this answer with what you did if you'd like - I'll accept any edits you throw in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
Accounts.ui.config({passwordSignupFields: ' EMAIL_ONLY' });
```

Source : http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Accounts-ui-config

Also you could just save the username in users `profile`

Comment: Without modifying the accounts-ui template this won't work for the OP's request (as far as I understand) - again, *IMHO* the OP will have to "roll his own" authentication one way or another.  Just doing that gives you a default form that asks for email only - no username.  It seams to me he still wants the username textbox to come up - but wants to bypass the part where it's checking for duplicate usernames.  He's going to have to create code which bypasses that, by rolling his own auth.

Comment: @scriptile, actually I need the username field at sign up for additional purposes in my app (not for sign in)